# HSSFWorkbook y FileOutputStream java

Tags: java, excel

Buenas tengo un problema en un código de java que tengo con estas dos clase al escribir en el fichero se me elimina lo que tenia antes alguien sabe alguna solución para no sobrescribir el fichero excel en java , gracias y un saludo.

```
dbf = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
//comprobamos el usuario para poder leer el xml  desde el servidor  
comprobarusu();
HSSFWorkbook a = archivoexcel();
HSSFSheet hoja = a.createSheet("LOGSSample");
String id = "";

try {
    dom = db.parse(ruta);
} catch (SAXException | IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SacarLogs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = dom.getDocumentElement();
org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("httpSample");

if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        HSSFRow filacabe = hoja.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell celdaca = filacabe.createCell((short) 0);
        HSSFCell celda2ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 1);
        HSSFCell celda3ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 2);
        HSSFCell celda4ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 3);
        HSSFCell celda5ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 4);
        HSSFCell celda6ca = filacabe.createCell((short) 5);
        celdaca.setCellValue("Nombre test");
        celda2ca.setCellValue("MENSAJE");
        celda3ca.setCellValue("MENSAJE");
        celda4ca.setCellValue("Entorno");
        celda5ca.setCellValue("Hora");
        celda6ca.setCellValue("FECHA");

        HSSFRow fila = hoja.createRow(i + 1);
        HSSFCell celda = fila.createCell((short) 0);
        HSSFCell celda2 = fila.createCell((short) 1);
        HSSFCell celda3 = fila.createCell((short) 2);
        HSSFCell celda4 = fila.createCell((short) 3);
        HSSFCell celda5 = fila.createCell((short) 4);
        HSSFCell celda6 = fila.createCell((short) 5);

        celda4.setCellValue(entorno);
        celda5.setCellValue(hora);
        celda6.setCellValue(fecha);

        org.w3c.dom.Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
        if (element.hasAttribute("lb")) {
            id = element.getAttribute("lb");
        }
        HSSFRichTextString texto = new HSSFRichTextString(id);
        celda.setCellValue(texto);
        String rm1 = "";
        if (element.hasAttribute("rm")) {
            rm1 = element.getAttribute("rm");
        }

        HSSFRichTextString nofail = new HSSFRichTextString(rm1);

        celda3.setCellValue(nofail);
        org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList2 = element.getElementsByTagName("assertionResult");
        if (nodeList2 != null && nodeList2.getLength() > 0) {

            for (int j = 0; j < nodeList2.getLength(); j++) {

                org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList3 = element.getElementsByTagName("failureMessage");
                if (nodeList3 != null && nodeList3.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node nodo = nodeList3.item(j);

                    if (nodo.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("failureMessage") && nodo.getTextContent() != null) {
                        HSSFRichTextString mensajefallo = new HSSFRichTextString(nodo.getTextContent());
                        celda2.setCellValue(mensajefallo);

                    }

                    if (nodo.getTextContent().getBytes().length == 0) {
                        String rm = "";
                        if (element.hasAttribute("rm")) {
                            rm = element.getAttribute("rm");
                        }

                        HSSFRichTextString nomensajefallo = new HSSFRichTextString(rm);

                        celda2.setCellValue(nomensajefallo);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        archivo(a, nombrearchivo);
```

Metodo archivo

```
public void archivo(HSSFWorkbook file, String nombrearchivo) {

    try {

        File af = new File("C:\\Users\\l.cabota\\Desktop\\logs\\logs\\" + nombrearchivo + ".xls");

        try (FileOutputStream elFichero = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\l.cabota\\Desktop\\logs\\logs\\" + nombrearchivo + ".xls")) {

            file.write(elFichero);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparte tu código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: public void archivo(HSSFWorkbook file, String nombrearchivo) {

        try {

            File af = new File("C:\\Users\\l.cabota\\Desktop\\logs\\logs\\" + nombrearchivo + ".xls");

            try (FileOutputStream elFichero = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\l.cabota\\Desktop\\logs\\logs\\" + nombrearchivo + ".xls")) {

                file.write(elFichero);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

Comment: ya lo tienes arriba